# Reading header values from a binary file blob in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, fileapi, file-header

Suppose I have a **bufferArray** object `buff` that holds a file.
Suppose, the file has a header with file properties that are different in size and are located at different offsets.

For example:

Offset | Length (bytes) | Property

- 0, 4, File signature
- 4, 2, Header size
- 6, 2, Version of file
- 8, 8, length property #1 in bytes
- 16, 8, length property #2 in bytes

etc.

So, I want to read those header entries.
**ArrayBuffer** cannot be accessed or modified directly in JS. We have to use **ArrayBufferView**.

But the entries are of different size: We have 2, 4, 8 byte (and possibly other sizes) values to read.  Subsequently, will I need to use multiple **ArrayBufferView**'s to read a header from 1 file?

```
const buff = new ArrayBuffer();

var byte2 = new Uint16Array(buffer, byteOffset, length);
var byte4 = new Uint32Array(buffer, byteOffset, length);
var byte8 = ? // JS does not support 64 bit Ints. What should I do?

var signature = byte4[0];
var headerSize = byte2[2];
var fileVersion = byte2[3];

property1 = ? // no 64 bit Int support in JS
property2 = ? // no 64 bit Int support in JS
```

So, my question is: Is having multiple **ArrayBufferView**'s the way to go, or is there a more elegant approach? Like, setting a **JS** equivalent of a **C** struct in one go.

Also, how do I read and store 64 bit (8 byte) Ints from the file header in JS?
(Sorry for the second sub-question, but they are really interconnected for this application case. Maybe, post 2 separate answers for extra points.)